# wiring furnace blower to turn on when make up air damper is powered to open

Tags: hvac

I have a make up air damper that is opened to supply make up air to the system return air duct when the kitchen range hood is operating.  There is a pressure sensor in the range hood vent duct that sends 24 VAC signal to damper motor.  I want the furnace blower to come on when this occurs to help pull more make up air into the return.  I have furnace control board with a smart t-stat (Ecobee) wiring landed on the Y,W,R,G and C terminals.  Could I simply cut one of the wires coming from the pressure sensor and connect each end between the R and G terminals?  Or what would be recommended method?  I would like the heat or cooling to also be able to continue to turn on fan when heat or cooling is calling from the t-stat.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Why do you want this to happen; is it just "more air must be better"? And, props for [taking our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting; few newbies do.

Comment: How is the kitchen range hood (and the vent damper) controlled? Also, is it possible to run a new cable between the damper motor and the furnace?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned

Answer (score 0):

I understand you probably have a tight house and when your exhaust fan is on you want the furnace to provide fresh air to keep the smoke out of the house. 
I have used the power to the fan  to pull in a relay.  The relay and the furnace transformer to power the call for the fan just like if the thermostat was in fan only, this way if the call for heat or cooling is active when you are cooking there will be no problems with the controls. You will need to run a piece of Romex to a box in the area of the thermostat I have done this in the attic the hardest part was fishing the wires up the walls from the thermostat. I did this on the last house tract we built as one of the features of our buildings.

Edit for 24v operation after re reading.

Be cautious using power from separate systems , I re read the question and you could use a Separate 24 v relay that is powered from the damper 24 v to create a signal from your thermostat to your fan control signal.
then you would not need to tap the fan supply, when there is 24 v for the damper that same 24v can be used to fire a relay (think electronic switch) when the relay fires or pulls in it can send the signal to the fan the same as your thermostat so it won’t matter if the furnace is running or not.
when the 24v is there the relay turns on the fan. 
I would caution from Using the 24 from another source can cause many problems including damage to your thermostat and or furnace control board , the fan is usually the green wire or G terminal at the stat or control board, the red wire goes to the R or V terminal this is your hot  if you jumper red to green the fan should start , now add the relay on the red Common wire for the relay and and the green to the NO (normally open) contacts for the relay then run some door bell wire or better from the relay coil a1 and a2 or input and the other end to the damper where the pressure switch powers it or come from the pressure switch itself. If your 24 v comes from the furnace it is much easier just take the hot to the green terminal as the common or c wire should be the same, if not powered by the furnace use a relay as I have seen folks blow up 800$ control boards & thermostats because they had 2 different transformers.

Comment: Thanks very much for the input.  However, I don't really understand exactly what the process is.  Anyway, in a nut shell I want the furnace fan to turn on when the makeup air damper opens.  I'm wondering if I installed a switch that would be automatically activated when the damper opened and connected the switch across the R and G terminals on the furnace control board, thereby jumpering across R and G, would that turn on the fan?  And if it did, would the T-stat still function to call for heat or cooling operation?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this device is what you are looking for. 
https://www.nktechnologies.com/current-sensing-switches/as1-ft-go-current-sensing-switch/
Check your schematic for the right terminals to extend to the contacts on this switch. I believe maybe terminals r and g are power and blower control.
Double check though.
The current needed to close the contact is 5.6 amps. But don't worry. 
If the wire goes through once then it sees  what the damper uses in current.
If it goes through twice then it sees double what the damper uses in current.
You get the idea!
My thought is monitor the damper motor current to activate the furnace blower using the current sensing switch.

Comment: Thanks to Ed Beal and User68386.  The current sensor mentioned cost about $100.  I'm thinking that if the furnace blower can be turned on by jumpering between the R and G terminal then I can connect a switch to those terminals to accomplish that.  The switch would be activated by damper position.  When damper opens, that position would close the N.O.switch to provide jumper across R and G terminals on furnace control board.  When the damper closes, that position deactivates switch to open the loop.  That solution would save quite a bit of money vs the current sensor.

Comment: BTW, the damper open - close is activated by a pressure sensor in the range hood duct.